# Running Unit / Integration tests through an in-memory SQL database using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration, azure-devops, xunit

I'm trying to setup a CI Build Definition in visual studio team services that runs a number of tests. I currently have these tests setup with xUnit (as shown below).

[image: Screenshot of a test]

These tests use the Entity Framework's in-memory relational sql database. The test classes extend the below code and manipulate the database using the DbContext variable (see below).

[image: Screenshot of dbcontext code]

When the tests are run locally, they all pass and perform fine. When the build is run on the online CI platform, while the build succeeds using the hosted VS2017 agent, all of the tests fail due to the below error.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

[image: Other screenshot of the error message]

We still wish to use the online hosted agents as an on-premisis agents (which I understand are a bit more configurable) won't necessarily be suitable.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In memory sql database is SqlLite database. You need to search about this and have proper connection string configured in your test projects.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I originally used SQLite however it doesn't support dropping columns, altering columns, adding constraints, dropping constraints, etc. which I need as part of my migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, you are using `UserSqlServer` method that is used for SQL database, you need to call `UseInMemoryDatabase` method.